# Can doGET() receive other arguments than request, response?

Tags: java, http, servlets, gwt

I am building a GWT servlet that receives a hashmap and creates excel file from data, converts to byte array and then sends back to client. Can I send my hashmap to my doGet method?

Comment: Put the elments in the http body , and read it from doGet.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I am calling my servlet with domain.com/servlet. But before getting a response (excel file) I want to do some computations that creates the excel file from a hashmap!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling my exportToExcel server-side code as before, and then in my onSucces I set a window open for my http servlet.